# Не конвертируется изображение из byte[] в BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf

Использую TagLib чтобы преобразовать картинку альбома из mp3 в byte[]:

```
TagLib.File tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(el);
IPicture Pic = tagFile.Tag.Pictures[0];
byte[] Picture = Pic.Data.Data.ToArray();
```

Записываю в бд, затем достаю и пытаюсь конвертировать в BitmapImage и записать в контрол Image FindedSongPicture в главном окне:

Конвертирующая ф-я:

```
private BitmapImage Bitmap2BitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
         bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
         ms.Position = 0;
         bi.BeginInit();
         bi.StreamSource = ms;
         bi.EndInit();

         return bi;
    }
}
```

Исполняемый код, где byte[] song.songPicture:

```
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(song.songPicture))
{
    using (var img = Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
        FindedSongPicture.Source = Bitmap2BitmapImage(img as Bitmap);
    }
}
```

В итоге в Image ничего не отображается

Первый кусок берёт картинку альбома из mp3 файла и вытягивает из неё byte[], TagLib позволяет

Второй кусок это ф-я преобразования из Bitmap в BitmapImage, так как в контрол Image на главной форме можно запихнуть только BitmapImage

3-ий кусок преобразует byte[] в Bitmap, вызывает ф-ю Bitmap->BitmapImage и пихает BitmapImage в контрол Image в главном окне, FindedSongPicture это имя контрола Image в главном окне

song.songPicture это byte[]

TagLib - библиотека для работы с тагами mp3 файла

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то у вас всё слишком сложно. Последовательность байт в `MemoryStream`, из него в `System.Windows.Forms.Bitmap`, из него в другой `MemoryStream`, из него в `BitmapImage`. Куча возможностей ошибиться по дороге.

Попробуйте проще:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(song.songPicture))
{
    FindedSongPicture.Source =
        BitmapFrame.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```

Ну или если хотите использовать `BitmapImage`, добавьте `bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;` перед `bi.EndInit()`. И возможно ещё `bi.Freeze()`.

Comment: Опять же спасибо, я просто сконвертировал кучу ответов по этой проблеме в один

Comment: Большинство решает задачу неправильно, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯